# utf-8 support for barryvdh/laravel-dompdf on laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, dompdf

i am using dompdf package from [here](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf).
i am able to load my view file into pdf. but the text that is supposed to be in Chinese did not display out.  i have tried adding font face but still does not solve the issue.
Sample of my view file

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<style>
@font-face {
font-family: firefly;
src: {{ storage_path().'/fonts/fireflysung.ttf' }};
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Summary Invoice Report</h3>

Date from {{ $from }} to {{ $to }}
<p>Date: {{ date('Y-m-d') }}</p>
<table border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>INVOICE</th>
        <th>DATE</th>
        <th>COMPANY NAME</th>
        <th>TOTAL AMT</th>
        <th>OUTSTANDING</th>
        <th>CANCEL AMT</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
@foreach ($data as $row)
    <tr>
        <td> {{ $row->invoice_number }} </td>
        <td>{{ $row->created_at }} </td>
        <td>{{ $row->customer_name }} </td>
        <td>{{ $row->total_amount }} </td>
        <td>{{ $row->total_outstanding_amount }} </td>
        <td>{{ $row->cancel_amount }} </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">Total</td>
    <td>{{ $total_invoice }}</td>
    <td>{{ $total_outstanding }}</td>
    <td>{{ $total_cancel }}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you got an encoding error, take it up on hes github page.

Comment: Did you set the header, that is if you are using a view? The header he says to use to support utf-8 is <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> . Im asking as the head tags are not present on the code you have supplied.

Comment: It's a bit out of date, but take a look at the [Unicode How-To](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/UnicodeHowTo) for an overview of the process of supporting non WindowsANSI-encoded characters. Also, check out these two answers: stackoverflow.com/a/24517882/264628; stackoverflow.com/a/24688996/264628

Comment: Also, to help debug rendering issues in dompdf it helps to see the HTML you feed into it, not the PHP that generates the HTML (though sometimes seeing the process can help identify other issues).

Comment: @MattBurrow i have added the header to my template file.. updated my question with full template file

Comment: Is the Firefly font loaded. You should see an entry in {DOMPDF_FONT_DIR}/dompdf_font_family_cache.php (DOMPDF_FONT_DIR by default is dompdf/lib/fonts)?

Comment: Also, just loading the font isn't enough. You are defining it as the font for the relevant text somewhere, yes? e.g. `<span style="font-family: firefly">...</span>`.